# Does Craft/Twig help with cache-busting js/css?

Tags: templating

Usually, I would use PHP to append the filetime of a file provide cache-busting. Does Craft or Twig do anything that can help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Craft/Twig itself doesn't really do anything in regards to cache busting your assets. Bust is one tool, and you'd also want to take a look at the awesome [Minimee plugin](https://github.com/johndwells/craft.minimee) port.

Comment: Yes, John deserves a special place in heaven/St. Tropez & 100 billion dollars. Perhaps some nice craft beer. He likes that.